# Asp.net core 2.0 Angular template: add identity and authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm starting a new project and I will make it using Visual Studio 2017 and that Asp.net Core 2.0 Angular Template. In this project I need to have authentication with roles. Here is where I'm getting lost since I've been not working with asp.net for some years.

My question is: how to add authentication, via JWT, to this Asp.net Core 2.0 angular template? I don't want to use an external authentication service like Auth0. I want to use my own users. I saw that it can be done using Identity server 4, but so far every tutorial I find is confusing to me.

What are the steps I should follow to implement these requirements? The answer could be just the name of the features I have to implement. I can google and learn how to implement. I just need the names

Thanks for any help

Comment: check out this answer, might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/44528686/3485837

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EntityFramework or EntityFrameworkCore and also you are using entity framework migration, you can easily inherit your *DbContext* class from *IdentityDbContext*. Check below code as an example :

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Phenomenal.WebApp.Domain.BlogModels;

    namespace Phenomenal.WebApp
    {
        public class PhenomenalContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
        {
           public PhenomenalContext(DbContextOptions<PhenomenalContext> options)
               :base(options)
           {

        }

        public DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }



    }
}
```

Once you saved your DbContext you can run below commands in "Package Manager Console" to add Identity Schema and tables to your database :

1) `Add-Migration CreateIdentitySchema`

This will create the migration class.

2) `Update-Database`

This will update your database and add all the Identity tables.

3) `Script-Migration` in entityframeworkcore or `Update-Database -script` in entityframework

This command will return the SQL queries for creating the schema and tables if you want to create manually.

I hope this helps.